# Center text even when there is a right or left button in the div?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following css to center text:

```
.text-align-center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

However, when there is a left or right arrow icon in the `<div>`, the text gets slightly off center.

Is it possible to make the centering ignore the arrow icons?

EDIT:

Here is my HTML where text is not quite centered because of the arrow icon

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div ng-click="okDate(unreported)" class="item item-text-wrap item-icon-right text-align-center">
        {{ formattedRecentDate(unreported) }}
        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: What do you use to display a *left or right arrow icon*?

Comment: Post your html please

Comment: So many different options - all depend on your scenario - please add some more to the question, specifically the html with and without your 'arrow icons'.   How much text is involved (eg is it a simple "next" or a paragraph)?  Do you have *both* left/right icons, or only one?  Is there *always* an icon or only sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a wrapper for both arrows. Left and right. And then place the content in another div between the arrows, with centered text.

Then you can hide one of the arrows depending on your needs(hide the left arrow when you are on the first page for example).

Keep in mind to hide only the arrow not the wrapper, in order to keep the centering.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it like this:

```
.exclude-my-width {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1efpx6eq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is how you want to do it but i think its the easy way to achieve this if the content is not variable

Define `width` of element and set `margin` to auto

```
<div>
   <i class='arrow_icon'></i>Hello There
</div>

<style>
    div{
        width:100px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm hoping to find a solution where I don't have to specify any widths